# Get random record giving priority to record not already chosen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find a way to get some random record without repetition at least until I take all the records from a table one time.

I have a table with some questions (3000).

I create a quiz selecting some random questions (30). I need to create quiz with all the question so without repetition until I use all the 3000 questions. Then I can begin to us the questions for another cycle.

In a single user environment I can add a field "count" to increase in my Question table every time I use a question, but I have a multiuser environment, so I can't pollute the Question table.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You must create an intermediate table.

Assuming your models are `User` and `Question`:

```
rails g migration create_users_questions user_id:integer question_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

This will generate a `users_questions` table in your database.

Then, in your `user.rb`:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
```

and in your `question.rb`:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Each row of the new table will contain a `user_id` and a `question_id`

So, to get unused questions for user `@user`:

**Generic Syntax**

```
@unused_questions = Question.where('id not in (?)',@user.questions.map(&:id))
```

**Rails ~> 4.0 Syntax** [thanks D-Side]

```
@unused_questions = Question.where.not(id:@user.question_ids)
```

And to add a new, used, question (let's say @question) to @user:

```
@user.questions<<@question
```

That's it, end of story...

Finally, to reset status of the @user's questions:

```
if @unused_questions.empty?       # we have defined that above
    @user.questions.clear
end
```

And then you go adding once again...

Comment: Just one thing. Watch this: `Question.where.not(id: @user.question_ids)`. UPD: Uh, the question appears to be quite old, this is Rails 4's `not` syntax.

Comment: @D-side, will this work? `:id` represents integer, and `@user.question_ids` is an array

Comment: It will. It's slightly more complicated than that. `question_ids` is a relation that `SELECT`s integers from the database. A relation in `where`-conditions is interpreted as `IN (subquery)` (with added `NOT` for `where.not`). So, effectively, this will even be a single query like `SELECT questions.* WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT questions.id <...>)`

Comment: Allow me to disagree.. `question_ids` is in fact an array. (you can confirm if you run in console something like `@user.question_ids.class`. And to agree that it does in fact work, I've tested it. So, I will update my answer, thanks.

Comment: How did I get a subquery then.. I'll inspect that. Maybe a certain version of Rails is relevant.

Comment: You're right. However, `Question.where.not(id: @user.questions)` seems to do what I was originally intending (although it doesn't look too type-safe, it selects the proper values). On Rails 4.1+ at least.

Answer (score 0):

IF you don't want to add any database fields, the best way will be using redis

1- Adding all ure questions ids in redis

```
$redis.sadd 'set_one', Question.pluck(:id)
```

2- Hitting on a method which selects a random id  and removes it from the list

```
def get_rand_question
 random_id =  $redis.spop "set_one"
 Question.find random_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use cache for store ids of sorted unused questions.

```
available_question_ids = Rails.cache.read('available_question_ids')
if available_questions_ids.nil? || available_question_ids.empty?
  available_question_ids = Question.pluck(:id).to_a.shuffle
end
quiz_questions_ids = available_question_ids.pop(30)
Rails.cache.write('available_question_ids', available_question_ids)
```

Now you can find your questions with `quiz_questions = Question.find(quiz_questions_ids)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to add another model to track user interactions with a specific question.

User Questions:

- belongs_to :user
- belongs_to :question
- used (boolean)

User:

- has_many :user_questions
- has_many :questions, through: :user_questions

Then you are going to need to run a limited, randomized query:

user_question = User.user_questions.where(used: false).order("RANDOM()").first

This will get you your next question to use. Once it's been answered you will mark it as used so it's not picked up again.

When you regenerate a quiz you would need to reset to false. Alternatively you can use a count... but if your last quiz didn't use all the questions you will need to reset in some way or your counts will be off.